# What is the best way to treat large arrays of numbers in C++?

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

I need to deal with large arrays of float numbers (>200,000 numbers) and perform some maths with these arrays.

What do you suggest to treat these arrays so that I do not get any stack overflow problems?

**UPDATE**: I want to do simple and complex maths (sums, products, sin, cos, arctan) operations.

Comment: You can't get stack overflow problems if they're not on the stack.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with them.

Comment: Explaining what you wanna do with them might help

Comment: @chris: You can if you use a recursive algorithm.

Comment: @BenVoigt, True, I didn't think about that. If it's a problem, the heap solves half of the issues still.

Comment: @Ben not if you make your recursive code tail-call optimizable.

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi: You still can get stack overflow problems with tail recursion, depending on how smart the optimizer is.  Even one tail recursive case that the optimizer fails to eliminate is a sufficient counter-example to disprove a claim that says "You can't get stack overflow".

Comment: @Cris:I tried also to create arrays of pointers but I got segmentation fault.

Answer (score 6):

Plain numerical data you need to sequentially operate on?

```
std::valarray<double>
```

If profiling shows this is slowing you down, look for ways to make it faster by

```
std::valarray<double>::resize()
```

(yes, there's no `reserve()` unfortunately.

Why `std::valarray<double>` for numerical data? If you want to perform an operation on every element, just call

```
std::valarray<double>::apply(somefunction)
```

See for more information: [a C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray).

If you want to be able to `reserve()`, you'll need `std::vector`, which is also fine but doesn't have overloads for the math functions you may want to use.

---

EDIT: This is of course assuming you have enough memory to fit all your arrays into `std::valarray`s. If not, you should split the 200,000 rows up so that only so many floats are in memory at the same time.

Comment: Hey, rubenvb. This looks promising. The data are not really plain (they are results from observations of different objects) but yes, I want to sequentially perform operations. I will try that I come back to say what the result is.

Answer (score 1):

If your data are sparse, you could probably use boost's `sparse_matrix` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix_sparse.htm to represent you data structure and significantly reduce memory requirements.

Otherwise I would suggest looking into ways that you can split the data into chunks and work on one chunk in memory, then store that state to file and repeat.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you treat them like 10.000 per 10.000 then sum everything ?
It depends of what operations you are doing.

Comment: Hey NeeL, this also seems like a plausible suggestion, but I was trying to avoid doing that. Let's see if I manage!

Answer (score -3):

Depends on what you want to do with them.

Also, as chris said in the comments, dynamically allocate memory for your array (to get memory from the heap) and avoid using it as a local variable (which is allocated in the stack).

Comment: No, _do not_ use `new` unless you really know what you're doing. And even then, there's probably a better way.

Comment: Thanks for your corrections, but can anyone elaborate over why using new in this situation is bad?

Comment: Using `new` in (almost) _any_ situation is bad. Sure, you think you're cool and all by allocating a buffer with `new`, but then an exception is thrown, and bam, leak. Use smart pointers and/or containers instead.

Comment: Well probably I phrased by answer wrong. I didn't mean to use `new` per se, but allocate the memory dynamically (whatever the method). I'll edit my answer.